# Cannot figure out "Column in field list is ambiguous"

Tags: mysql

I have two tables STORE and SALE.

[image]

[image]

And my desired result is

[image]

I cannot figure out why my query below is having ERROR: **Column 'store_number' in field list is ambiguous**. I've been working on this simple query for an hour. Do appreciate if someone can help. Thank you so much.

```
SELECT store_number, city, revenue
FROM STORE
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM SALE) AS R
ON STORE.store_number = R.store_number;
```

Comment: Do **not** post images of tables. Paste the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements as **text** into your post.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the column `store_number` appears in both tables involved in the join, and the error message is MySQL saying that it doesn't know which one to use.  Use aliases here to resolve this problem:

```
SELECT st.store_number, st.city, sa.revenue
FROM STORE st
LEFT JOIN SALE sa
    ON st.store_number = sa.store_number;
```

Note: If you want to display a zero value for the revenue for those stores missing data, use `COALESCE(sa.revenue, 0)`.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply but I don't understand. I mentioned STORE.store_number in my query, why doesn't it work?

Comment: @SimonS. Yes, but not in the _select_ clause, where you have an unqualified `store_number`.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you so much.